# Sort an array by pattern preserving order of elements not found in pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

How to sort an array by pattern in such way that elements non-existing in the pattern are not moved to the end of array but their order is preserved?

There is an example:

```
let input = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Peach']
let pattern = ['Orange', 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Grape']

// desired output
let output = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape', 'Mango']
```

Length of pattern may be equal, less or higher than input array's length.

Standard sorting:

```
input.sort( (a, b) => {
    let indexA = pattern.indexOf(a);
    let indexB = pattern.indexOf(b);
    return Math.sign(indexA - indexB);
});

// result:
// Apple,Cherry,Mango,Orange,Peach,Banana,Grape
// elements that are not present in pattern have been moved to the left
```

However, we want to preserve relative position of elements that are not present in pattern array. What is the most efficient way to achieve it?

Example of use: reordering table columns (some may be hidden but we remember their order).

Comment: The position of `Cherry` is not preserved in output. Why?

Comment: The specification of your sorting doesn't feel very strict. I guess that's why you cannot implement it. How do you decide that `Chery` is before `Grape`? First write down the rules of your sorting. Then, it is likely to be easier to implement when you exactly know what to do.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `["Apple", "Orange", "Cherry", "Peach", "Mango", "Banana", "Grape"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patternElementIndexTable` is only there to speed up some operations, it could be removed, and `indexOf` taken at related positions. This would degrade the order of the algorithm and make problems when the input is e.g. larger than a few thousand items.

First, consider only the elements of `input` that occur in `pattern`, and create a mapping of the indexes between that list and `input`:

```
input.map((_, i) => i).filter(i => input[i] in patternElementIndexTable)
```

Then, i am mapping the assignment to any integer index of `intermediary` to change the related property of `input`, according to the mapping. This basically means operating on `intermediary` is "as if" operating on `input`, but just taking the desired elements into account.

As a result, sorting the intermediary then has the desired effect:

```js
let input = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Peach'];
let pattern = ['Orange', 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Grape'];

let patternElementIndexTable = pattern.reduce((p, c, i) => (p[c] = i, p), {});

let intermediary = new Proxy(
  Object.seal(input.map((_, i) => i).filter(i => input[i] in patternElementIndexTable)),
  {
    get: (target, prop) => {
      if (Number.isInteger(+prop) && +prop >= 0) {
        if (+prop >= target.length)
          return undefined;
        return input[target[prop]];
      }
      return target[prop];
    },
    set: (target, prop, value) => {
      if (Number.isInteger(+prop) && +prop >= 0) {
        if (+prop >= target.length) {
          return false;
        }
        input[target[prop]] = value;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
);

intermediary.sort((a, b) => patternElementIndexTable[a] - patternElementIndexTable[b]);

console.log(input);
```

I first thought about reimplementing some sort algorithm with that ability added, but this approach appears much more versatile (this should work for any other mutating operation that does not change the length aswell, e.g. `reverse`, `fill`, or custom made functions).

Note that one should not use `intermediary` after changing `input` by itself. Adding or removing elements is an invalid operation. Any changes to non-integer-index properties is an invalid operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the indices and get all indices of the wanted pattern in an array, sort it and map the original array and take at items of the pattern, the sorted items.

```js
var input = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Peach'],
    pattern = ['Orange', 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Grape'],
    patternO = Object.assign(...pattern.map((k, v) => ({ [k]: v }))),
    indices = [...input.keys()]
        .filter(i => input[i] in patternO)
        .sort((a, b) => patternO[input[a]] - patternO[input[b]]),
    result = input.map((j => (v, i) => v in patternO ? input[indices[j++]]: v)(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop `input` array and on each occurrence of element that exists in `pattern` array increment one counter variable and take element with that index.

```js
let input = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Grape', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Peach']
let pattern = ['Orange', 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Grape'];

let current = 0;
input.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (pattern.includes(e)) input[i] = pattern[current++]
})

console.log(input)
```

Comment: that works only if you have the same items to replace in the `input` and `pattern` array. maybe that is always the case ...

Comment: @Nina Scholz Yes, in that case he could first filter pattern array to remove elements that don't exist in input. Just `pattern = pattern.filter(e => input.includes(pattern))` before.

Comment: that assumes, only one pattern item is included, but it does not work for more than one (if wanted, blabla ;-) ).